# Cypher query to create some nodes if they don't exist, and to return more nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a tutorial for Neo4j, I want to create a basic set of nodes and edges, if none exist, and to return a selection of nodes that are available in the database. I know I can do it with this query...

```
MERGE
(hello {name: "Hello"})-[:LINK]->(world {name:"World"})
WITH (hello)
MATCH (node)
RETURN node
LIMIT 10
```

... but this use of `WITH` is not elegant. Is there a simpler way of ensuring that the "Hello" and "World" nodes exist, and to return additional nodes if such additional nodes exist?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to combine two unrelated queries? This does not appear, at first glance, to be a real world problem.

Comment: It's not a real-world problem. It's just for setting up a sandbox database for the purposes of a tutorial. If the learner makes changes to the sandbox database and then restarts the app, I want to be sure that there will be something to play with.

Comment: And if you change the order between MERGE & MATCH like this : MATCH (node)
MERGE (hello {name: "Hello"})-[:LINK]->(world {name:"World"})
RETURN node
LIMIT 10

Comment: @JamesNewton I would keep them separate queries (especially if the students can see the odd combined query). But if you really want a single query, what you are already doing seems good enough.

Comment: how about `MERGE (hello {name: "Hello"})-[:LINK]->(world {name:"World"}) return * ` ?

Comment: You can also use union, but I agree with @cybersam that this is a really unusual use.

Comment: @logisma I had already tried your solution, but if there were no nodes present at all, then the `MERGE` operation failed to create any.

Comment: @cybersam I've decided to use separate queries. It makes everything simpler to understand.

Comment: Neo4j also supports endpoints which let you give multiple queries in the same request.  Support for those batch / transaction endpoints depends on your library.